# PHP - Work out date

Tags: php

What I'm trying to do is check a table to see if a record exists with a date between two dates. The SQL query is currently

```
$q = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM member_games WHERE member = :userID AND game = :game AND (played BETWEEN :start AND :end)");
```

What I'm struggling with is getting the start/end dates

I want to check if there is a record between Saturday and Friday (and other days depending)

It seems to work if the date isn't a Saturday, but its incorrect if the date is currently a Saturday. I want to then check against the current Saturday, not the last one

This is how I work out the dates.

```
$sat = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last Saturday"));
$fri = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("friday"));
```

I know I can do an if statement to check if its Saturday like below, and change the strtotime to Saturday but I'm wondering if theres a better way of doing it

```
$today = date('N');
if($today == 6)
  $sat = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("Saturday"));
```

Comment: Do you **really** want today if today is Saturday? If you are using `$sat` as your `:start` date and `$fri` as your `:end` date then using today as `$sat` will mean no games ever qualify for your query.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is see if they've played a game between Saturday and Friday, so if they have played on the Saturday (today) then it would return a row, if they haven't, then it won't return anything

Comment: I know that is what you **want** to do. But if `$fri` is yesterday and `$sat` is today then your going to be checking if the dates are between today and yesterday, which will return `0` rows. The earlier date must be the first date in the `Between` clause.

Comment: $fri is giving me the expected date - 2018-06-22 so thats not an issue. If I print the values for the query, it gives me  (played BETWEEN '2018-06-09' AND '2018-06-22'), but the start should be 2018-06-16

Comment: I'm afraid you don't seem to understand. **Just as a test**, try hardcoding your dates with `$sat` (today) as your `:start` date and `$fri` (yesterday) as your `:end` date. No rows will qualify because the **1st** date in a `Between` must be **less than or equal to** the **2nd** date.

Comment: As I pointed out above, the Friday date is correct, 2018-06-22, which is the Friday coming, which is greater than today - 2018-06-16. I'm not looking for the last Friday, just the last Saturday. The code I have now works, I was just looking to see if there is an easier/better way of doing it

Comment: my mistake. I had `$fri` as 'last friday'. Ignore my previous comments.

Comment: $sat = (6 == date('N')) ? date('Y-m-d') : date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last saturday"));

Answer (score -1):

You should try Carbon library fuction `diffForHumans()`.

You can find more information here: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/